# How to set version info for static libraries using gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

New to development with GCC/ Linux world.

I have a project containing multiple static/ dynamic libraries that uses cmake. Is there a standard way to stamp version info for the libraries so we can know which version is being used by the consumer when it comes time to debug the issues?

Windows has a resource for such things: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: A static library is nothing more than a very simple archive of object files, and the archive structure doesn't really have anything like a "version number". A possible simple solution could be to encode the version number in the file-name of the library.

Comment: You could add an object module consisting just of the version number.

Comment: If someone else uses my static library, how do I know which version they were using?